# How to sprout turtles if consists 2 set of breed

Tags: netlogo

how to sprout all turtles for this case, if i want them locate only on blue patches.

```
breed [type1s type1]
breed [type2s type2]

to setup      
  create-type1s  population 
    [ set color white  
      set size 1 ]

  create-type2s ((percent_of_leader / 100) * population ) 
    [ set color black 
      set size 1] 
end
```

Before this, I only use below code. is there other way to sprout turtle for above case?

```
to setup
  ask n-of population patches with [ pcolor = blue]
  [ sprout 1
    [ set color white
      set size 1]]
end
```

Appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprout-type1s` to sprout turtles of the `type1` breed.  This is a version of NetLogo's `sprout-<breeds>` command.

(Tip: You can guess that the command that you want, if it exists, would either involve a special way of calling `sprout`, or a command with a related name.  So a good strategy would be to look in in the NetLogo Dictionary that's part of the Help system, searching for commands with names similar to "sprout", or scanning through the command names in the patches or turtles sections near the top of the dictionary.)

Comment: i tried to do like this 'create-type1s  (population) 
  [sprout-type1s 1
    [ set color white  
      set size 0.6 ]]', but its fail with error message **you can't use sprout-type1s in turtle context**

Comment: @juliana, only patches understand the commands `sprout` and `sprout-type1s`.  In the code in your posted question, you used `ask ... patches ... [sprout ...]`.  That's the correct way to use `sprout-` commands: You're asking the patches to sprout turtles (of breed type1).  When you enter `create-type1s <some-number> [sprout-type1s ...]`, you're asking *turtles* to sprout new turtles, but turtles don't know how to sprout turtles.  Only patches know how to create turtles by sprouting.